# How to avoid copy existing builds using Jenkins "Copy Artifacts plugin"?

Tags: jenkins, copy, duplicates, artifacts

I am using Jenkins "Copy Artifact" Plugin to copy the builds from another project to local PC. I getting an issue where jenkins is re-copying the existing builds, this is consuming lot of bandwidth and taking lot of time for the job to get finished.

How can we avoid copying the existing builds using 'Copy Artifact' plugin?, can we pass any arguments?